# warning about format not a string literal and no format arguments while compiling yacc file with gcc

Tags: gcc

This a a part of my yacc file, which i already compiled with bison,then when i want to use gcc to compile into executable,getting some warnings

```
search2:WORD    {fprintf(outFile_p,$1);}
search2:WHITE   {fprintf(outFile_p,$1);}
       |TAB     {fprintf(outFile_p,"\t");}
       |EOL     {counter=counter+1;fprintf(outFile_p,"\n");}
       |LBRAK   {fprintf(outFile_p,$1);}
       |RBRAK   {fprintf(outFile_p,$1);}
       |SIMICOL {fprintf(outFile_p,",");}
       |PERCENT {fprintf(outFile_p,"%%");}
       |PLUS    {fprintf(outFile_p,"+");}
       |ANY     {fprintf(outFile_p,$1);}
       |TCOM    {fprintf(outFile_p,"\"");}
       |MUL     {fprintf(outFile_p,$1);}
       |COM     {fprintf(outFile_p,";");}
       |LB      {fprintf(outFile_p,"[");}
       |RB      {fprintf(outFile_p,"]");}
```

those codes with "**{fprintf(outFile_p,$1);}**" I am having this warning when I want to compile using gcc

*format not a string literal and no format arguments*

If anyone can help me to fix this warning or do i need to post the whole code..........

the warnings look like this

```
y.y:509:5: warning: format not a string literal and no format arguments [-Wformat-security]
 search2:WORD    {fprintf(outFile_p,$1);}
     ^
y.y:510:5: warning: format not a string literal and no format arguments [-Wformat-security]
 search2:WHITE   {fprintf(outFile_p,$1);}
     ^
y.y:513:5: warning: format not a string literal and no format arguments [-Wformat-security]
        |LBRAK   {fprintf(outFile_p,$1);}
     ^
y.y:514:5: warning: format not a string literal and no format arguments [-Wformat-security]
        |RBRAK   {fprintf(outFile_p,$1);}
     ^
y.y:518:5: warning: format not a string literal and no format arguments [-Wformat-security]
        |ANY     {fprintf(outFile_p,$1);}
     ^
y.y:520:5: warning: format not a string literal and no format arguments [-Wformat-security]
        |MUL     {fprintf(outFile_p,$1);}
     ^
```

Answer (score 1):

Following is the declaration for fprintf() function.

```
int fprintf(FILE *stream, const char *format, ...)
```

Your code is missing format of `$1`

```
search2:WORD    {fprintf(outFile_p,"%s",$1);}
```

or you can use fputs as well -

```
search2:WORD    {fputs($1,outFile_p);}
```